# Is it still recommended to perform malware scans in safe mode?

Tags: windows, windows-10, anti-virus

In previous windows versions, it was recommended to run the antivirus as administrator in safe mode. Is that still recommended in windows 10 or it doesn't matter anymore?

Comment: When has anyone ever suggested scanning Windows in Safe Mode?  That’s a horrible idea, I have never heard that, from anyone with the experience to make that suggestion

Comment: @Ramhound Why would that be a horrible idea?

Comment: It’s unnecessary for one.  It actually reduces the chances of detection of malicious software because behavioral signatures can’t be used if the malware isn’t running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question still depends on how the threat. Consider a threat that is able to resist removal in normal mode but not in Safe Mode. In this case, running an antivirus scan in Safe Mode is still required.

Like previous versions of Windows, Safe Made still runs a reduced set of software. It's still dependent on the threat whether this makes a difference when it comes to detecting and removing threats.